# How do I convert RDBMS DDL to Hive DDL script

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, rdbms, sqoop

We've a large and disparate data sources including oracle,db2,mysql. We also need to append few audit columns at the end. 
I came across the following Java class org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveTypes. I am planning to create a simple interpreter that accepts RDBMS DDL and spits out Hive DDL script. Any pointers on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hive QL is more or less similar to normal RDBMS DDL. But there are certain things that it lacks and thats why it does not fully follow ANSI SQL. There is no automated process to convert it.

But you have to try running the SQL queries on Hive and wherever it violates you have to change the query according to hive.

For instance Hive takes only equality condition as join condition which is not the case in RDBMS.

For creating an interpreter yourself you first have to list down the common differences between RDBMS query construct and Hive QL construct. Whenever you encounter a RDBMS construct which according to your list will violate in hive the query gets rebuild as per hive. This replacement logic has to be coded.